# Inactivity Timeout in silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Navigation Frame in my MainPage.xaml whose content is set to Login.xaml.
From the LoginPage.xaml, I navigate to other pages as follows:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I need to implement a timoout on user inactivity that redirects to the Login.xaml from any page after 1 minute of inactivity (keyboard & mouse).

How can I do this.

EDIT: I need to call some clean up routines also when timeout happens.

Comment: Updated the answer. Did it fits to you?

Comment: Have a look at the answer here in [silverlight forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/166235/374562.aspx)